# NativeSearchQueryBuilder doesn't filter ids as expected

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

NativeSearchQueryBuilder doesn't filter ids as expected

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes("bi", "li").build())
    .withPageable(pageable).withIds(ids).build();
SearchHits<Profile> searchHits = esRestTemplate.search(query, Foo.class);


POST /foos/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "version": true,
  "explain": false,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "bi",
      "li"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  }
}

spring-data-elasticsearch 4.2.1
```

Comment: what's the problem? The Java code and the post request are the same - assuming that the index name for the `Foo` entity is _foos_.

Comment: The problem is even if we pass "ids", they are not getting used causing the entire index to be search

Comment: It seems, you are not aware what source filters are. Please read the Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/search-fields.html#source-filtering)